# Trouble with .gitignore and Pod Files

Tags: ios, github

Hello I am working on an xcode project that has a lot of Pods which makes my project exceed the 100 MB limit for being upload to github. The majority of this is due to to how large my pod files are.

I have tried this many times and I can't find a solution. I created a `.gitignore` file at the root of my Project within xcode. I then added the '''Pods''' into my `.gitignore` file and tried to load this fresh project into Github. It seems to not be working properly since when I try to push to GitHub it keeps saying it is exceeding. I literally just have 2 VC in my project with no assets, thus it has to be my pods (Mapbox). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. [Here is a screen shot to the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46ipd.png) I have attached a screenshot to show where my file is, what is in my .gitignore and what the issue is.

[Edited with update (failed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jxoz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In your `.gitignore` file, make sure it is `Pods/` and not `Pods`. Save the file and quit the text editor. You should be good to push to Github.

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work, I have posted another photo in the "Edited with update (failed)" link.

Comment: Did you stage the newly updated ```.gitignore``` file?